# Is my ISP hacking me?

Tags: attacks

[image]Today I was trying to enter my routers admin page. I put the default IP address starting with 192.168. I couldn't login so ran ipconfig, and I discovered that I was assigned a Class A address. I was confused because I didn't change my IP so i typed that A class IP which starts with 10.100 a file downloaded and installed in my computer. I ran network map in Windows 7 and I found a computer not in my network taking the routers name.

Is my ISP hacking me?
Thank You

[image]

Comment: Unlikely an ISP, probably some other malicious actor.  You can press the image button in the toolbar above the text box.  It should bring up a prompt to upload a photo.

Comment: thank you, but who would use class A ip address!!!

Comment: @obdaldh The "Class" system of IP addressing is largely considered defunct in favour of classless IP addresses. In addition, if it was a "Class A" address your subnet mask would be 255.0.0.0 (or /8) not 255.255.255.0

Comment: Are you using wireless WEP or do you have a weak wifi password? What you need to do is to reset the router and set a strong WPA2 password.

Comment: @obdaldh Many home routers use 10.x.x.x/24 for its default IP scheme.  My Comcast router at home uses this.  It is common.

Comment: "a file was downloaded and installed on my computer" what file it is ? And why did you execute and install it ?

Comment: @Andre Daniel, there is no traces of the file, and i didn't execute it. after i typed the gateway address in the browser it was installed at once.

Comment: obdalh - without being able to say what that file was, there is nothing useful we can do for you. Personally, I'm not sure there is anything wrong with your network at all. Check all the devices on the network - those 2 linksys icons may be the same device.

Answer (score 6):

It is highly unlikely that your ISP would hack you, since they can easily (and without a trace) watch all your data go by on the wire.

However, since you said there is a strange computer connected to your network, that sounds like an intruder on your network, perhaps trying to perform a MiTM attack.

You should reset your router to factory settings, use a strong (24 character, randomly generated with special characters) password, disable WEP and WPS, use WPA-2, disable remote access to router panel, and force it to be on a wired connection to access admin area.